# Configure WCF binding behind a F5 load balancer

Tags: wcf

I am trying to set up a WCF service on IIS behind a F5 load balancer. The F5 handles the SSL and the WCF service is on HTTP. This seems to be fairly standard scenario for deployment but googling does not help much. 
Thanks in advance if someone could answer this.

Comment: Please expand your question. What is the problem? I guess it'd have something to do with the client wanting to use a secure binding using SSL while the service doesn't know about that? Explain the exact problem and show your configuration and errors (if you get any).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clearusernamebinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get to configure SSL on F5 load balancer by going through this [link](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_implementation/sol_http_ssl.html).

Additionally if you have your WCF service that has basicHttpBinding with userName/Password Validation and you want the SSL to be offloaded at the load balancer you can use [ClearUserNameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) to pass username/password over Http as said by Yaron.